# Getting an environment variable set in VSCODE based on CMake variant

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, pybind11

I'm using Pybind11 to make C++/Python modules and apparently the output .DLLs need to be in the PYTHONPATH for the module to be imported (appending to sys.path does not work).

I'm using CMake variants to set various builds, and that makes separate output directories per variant.

I'm at a loss to find a way to set the PYTHONPATH environment variable in the integrated terminals (and jupyter notebooks) based on my chosen variant.

Any suggestions?

```
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}\\build\\${variant:platform}"
    },
```

does not work (it doesn't seem to substitute ${variant:platform}).

in the `.env` file, neither `${workspaceRoot}` nor `${variant:platform}` seem to be available

Comment: Did you see the VS Code environment variables reference [page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_predefined-variables)? The `workspaceRoot` variable is deprecated, and superseded by `workspaceFolder`.

Comment: @squareskittles  while it's deprecated, it still functions in settings.json.  Changing to workspaceFolder makes no difference

Comment: Did you try setting these in your `launch.json` file?

Comment: @squareskittles  sadly, `${variant:platform}` doesn't seem to expanded there either.